# Pandas Is it possible to add new time values with empty values in columns in a csv with a time sequence?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks something like this

| Time | OI | V |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:23 | 5.4 | 27 |
| 10:00:24 | -0.7 | 1 |
| 10:00:28 | -0.5 | 4 |
| 10:00:29 | 0.2 | 12 |

Can I somehow add new time values using Pandas while filling the columns with zeros or Nan? For the entire csv file.

What would have turned out something like that ?

| Time | OI | V |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:23 | 5.4 | 27 |
| 10:00:24 | -0.7 | 1 |
| 10:00:25 | 0 | Nan |
| 10:00:26 | 0 | Nan |
| 10:00:27 | 0 | Nan |
| 10:00:28 | -0.5 | 4 |
| 10:00:29 | 0.2 | 12 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes, create `DatetimeIndex` and add missing values by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), last replace `NaN`s in `OI` column:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df = df.set_index('Time').asfreq('S').fillna({'OI':0})
df.index = df.index.time
print (df)
           OI     V
10:00:23  5.4  27.0
10:00:24 -0.7   1.0
10:00:25  0.0   NaN
10:00:26  0.0   NaN
10:00:27  0.0   NaN
10:00:28 -0.5   4.0
10:00:29  0.2  12.0
```

---

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df = df.set_index('Time').asfreq('S').fillna({'OI':0}).reset_index()
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.time
print (df)
       Time   OI     V
0  10:00:23  5.4  27.0
1  10:00:24 -0.7   1.0
2  10:00:25  0.0   NaN
3  10:00:26  0.0   NaN
4  10:00:27  0.0   NaN
5  10:00:28 -0.5   4.0
6  10:00:29  0.2  12.0
```